# UIKit. How to set Transparent color?

Tags: iphone, uikit

Is there any way to set any color of UIImage (or it CALayer content) as transparent color?

I cannot use single image resource(PNG file) with built-in transparency.

I need to hide some area from first Layer by overlaying second Layer with specific color at that place. So I need to set this specific color as "transparent color" before assembled image drawing.

Image area I need to hide is like background - **i.e. specific color will be started from image borders through whole perimeter.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors. I recommend reading the ["Bitmap Images and Image Masks"](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHBCGB) part of the Quartz Programming Guide, and check some example code. It's slightly more low-level than your average Cocoa code, but not very hard to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried it before for other purpose... Looks like it's only way to meet my current needed.